# bootstrap input form-control display horizontally than cascading

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have trouble with input bootstrap form-control in a table column. I dont want it to be cascading ontop of each other but i want it stacked horizontally like how tables rows should be.

Here is the problem code:

```
        <td colspan="4">
         a:
         <input class="form-control" id="a" type="text" value="a" />                
         b:
         <input class="form-control" id="a" type="text" value="a" />                  
        </td>
```

And here is the example to see the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/gV6y8/27/

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues in your code, you should wrap inputs in the `form-group` class, also `form-control` automatically takes 100% width.  Furthermore, it sounds like you want to be using a `form-inline`.

Try this:

HTML:

First change: add `form-inline` class

```
<table id="paymenttable" class="table table-condensed form-inline">
```

Second change: add `form-group` and change width of `form-control`

```
<td colspan="4">
    <div class="form-group">
        a:
        <input class="form-control table-input" id="a" type="text" value="a" />        
        b:
        <input class="form-control table-input" id="a" type="text" value="a" />                 
    </div>
</td>
```

Add to your CSS:

```
.table-input {
    width:40%;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gV6y8/28/)